# How to show json encoded array in Sweet alert message

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-8, sweetalert

I'm using Laravel 8 and [Sweet Alert](https://github.com/realrashid/sweet-alert) and I wanted to show the error messages that were caught by error Exception as Sweet Alert error popup message.

Basically here is my Controller method:

```
try{
   ...
}catch(\Exception $e){
   // Alert::error('Error Title', 'Error Message');

   return json_encode(['status' => '500', 'msg' => __('message.error-server')]);
}
```

So as you can see I have json encoded an associative array that holds the information of the error message but I don't want to `return` it. In fact I have to show it as `Alert::error(...)`.

So how can I do that?

---

**UPDATE 1:**

I just tested this but not showing me the error as Alert:

```
public function destroy(User $user)
    {
        try{
            $useradasd->is_active = 0;
            $useradasd->is_deleted = 1;
            $useradasd->remover_id = Auth::id();
            $useradasd->save();
        }catch(\Exception $e){
            $attributes = ['status' => '500', 'msg' => __('message.error-server')];

            $dataAttributes = array_map(function($value, $key) {
                return $key.'=>'.$value;
            }, array_values($attributes), array_keys($attributes));

            $associativeString = implode(', ', $dataAttributes);
            Alert::error($associativeString);
        }
        Alert::success('Removed', 'That user is deleted');
        return back();
    }
```

---

**UPDATE 2**:

I just tried this, but does not catch the error exception and show me the `Alert::success(...)` instead.

```
public function destroy(User $user)
    {
        try{
            $useradasd->is_active = 0;
            $useradasd->is_deleted = 1;
            $useradasd->remover_id = Auth::id();
            $useradasd->save();
        }catch(\Exception $e){
            $attributes = ['status' => '500', 'msg' => __('message.error-server')];

            $dataAttributes = array_map(function($value, $key) {
                return $key.'=>'.$value;
            }, array_values($attributes), array_keys($attributes));

            $associativeString = implode(', ', $dataAttributes);
            Alert::error('Error',$associativeString);
        }
        Alert::success('Removed', 'That user is deleted');
        return back();
    }
```

---

**UPDATE #3:**

I can finally get the error:

[image]

But I wanted to show `$attributes['status']` which is **500** as Error Title and the body of that error contains `$attributes['msg']`. How can I do that?

Comment: I advise you to try and understand the solutions instead of just copy pasting them to see if they work. Check my updated answer for detailed information on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$attributes = ['status' => '500', 'msg' => __('message.error-server')

$dataAttributes = array_map(function($value, $key) {
    return $key.'=>'.$value;
}, array_values($attributes), array_keys($attributes));

$associativeString = implode(', ', $dataAttributes);
```

What this does basically is, it will convert the associative array to string first and then you can use the final string i.e.`$associativeString` in your alert as:

```
Alert::error($associativeString);
```

this will output like:

```
status => 500, msg => Internal Server Error
```

you can modify `return $key.'=>'.$value;` inside map to shape the final output the way you want.

### UPDATE #1

Looking at the SweetAlert docs you used, I believe it follows the syntax of `Alert::[type]([Title],[message])`, You can update the alert from this:

```
Alert::error($associativeString);
```

to this:

```
Alert::error('Error',$associativeString);
```

### UPDATE #2

```
public function destroy(User $user)
    {
        try{
            $useradasd->is_active = 0;
            $useradasd->is_deleted = 1;
            $useradasd->remover_id = Auth::id();
            $useradasd->save();
            throw new Exception("Custom Exception from try block");
        }catch(\Exception $e){
            $attributes = ['status' => '500', 'msg' => $e->getMessage()];

            $dataAttributes = array_map(function($value, $key) {
                return $key.'=>'.$value;
            }, array_values($attributes), array_keys($attributes));

            $associativeString = implode(', ', $dataAttributes);
            Alert::error('Error',$associativeString);
        }
        return back();
    }
```

### UPDATE #3

You should work on improving your concepts of arrays in php and how they work learn [How PHP associative arrays work](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_associative.asp), now according to your requirement you should not convert the associative array to string as I suggested in my original answer. try this instead:

```
public function destroy(User $user)
    {
        try{
            $useradasd->is_active = 0;
            $useradasd->is_deleted = 1;
            $useradasd->remover_id = Auth::id();
            $useradasd->save();
            throw new Exception("Custom Exception from try block");
        }catch(\Exception $e){
            $attributes = ['status' => '500', 'msg' => $e->getMessage()];

            Alert::error($attributes['status'],$attributes['msg']);
        }
        return back();
    }
```

the `Alert::error()` takes two parameters the first one is Title and the second is the message, you just have to fetch the value from related keys of associative array i.e. `status` and `msg` in our case.

Comment: Can you check my **UPDATE** about your code plz

Comment: Check now I have updated.

Comment: I just tried it but still does not catch the Error Exception :( Please see **UPDATE  #2**

Comment: first of all when using try-catch you should put the related thing in their respective position, the ```Alert:success()``` should go inside try but not outside the entire try-catch block. Second, if it is not throwing the exception it means the try block is executing correctly and there's no exception.

Comment: How can I throw the Exception? As you see here I used `$useradasd` instead of `$user` to get the error exception.

Comment: this is becuase php doesn't think ```$useradasd``` is undefined. try and doing something else, either throw the exception yourself with ```throw new Exception("Throwing exception from try block myself");``` or try division by zero inside the try block.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246020/discussion-between-salman-malik-and-nagidi).

Comment: I can finally get the error (see **UPDATE #3**). But I wanted to show $attributes['status'] which is 500 as Error Title and the body of that error contains $attributes['msg']. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This Should Work

```
Alert::error(json_encode(['status' => '500', 'msg' => __('message.error-server')],JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

Comment: I tested it but does not even reach the Exception !

Comment: You Can Setup The Errors Json Data in a Varriable Then Use When Needed $message = json_encode(['status' => '500', 'msg' => __('message.error-server')],JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);